# Convert pixelBuffer(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar) to CIImage

Tags: ios, swift, yuv, ciimage, cvpixelbuffer

Now I am trying to convert pixelBuffer to CIImage, but fails.

When pixelBuffer type is kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange, the following code can be executed without errors.

`let sourceImage = CIImage.init(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer, options: nil)`

However when pixelBuffer type is kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar, it fails.

The log is as follows.

`[api] -[CIImage initWithCVPixelBuffer:options:] failed because its pixel format y420 is not supported.`

Therefore, I want to know how to convert pixelBuffer type or to convert pixelBuffer(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar) to CIImage.

Please teach me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [vImageConverter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimageconverter)

With this you can convert to ARGB8888 `vImageConvert_420Yp8_CbCr8ToARGB8888`
and muss create a `vImage_Buffer`

Example for conversion matrix

```
/// This is the YCbCr to RGB conversion opaque object used by the convert function.
private var conversionMatrix: vImage_YpCbCrToARGB = {
    var pixelRange = vImage_YpCbCrPixelRange(Yp_bias: 0, CbCr_bias: 128, YpRangeMax: 255, CbCrRangeMax: 255, YpMax: 255, YpMin: 1, CbCrMax: 255, CbCrMin: 0)
    var matrix = vImage_YpCbCrToARGB()
    vImageConvert_YpCbCrToARGB_GenerateConversion(kvImage_YpCbCrToARGBMatrix_ITU_R_709_2, &pixelRange, &matrix, kvImage420Yp8_CbCr8, kvImageARGB8888, UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))
    return matrix
}()
```

Example code: [CapturedImageSampler.swift](https://gist.github.com/JoshuaSullivan/765ba8cfb03ca7bbf14ef68731872750)

Comment: error  has occured. 

`error: vImage_YpCbCrToARGB has unknown version`

Comment: you must import Accelerate

Comment: here is an example [CapturedImageSampler.swift](https://gist.github.com/JoshuaSullivan/765ba8cfb03ca7bbf14ef68731872750)